# Why does an empty cell in UITableView has grey background on device but not on simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I created a Master-Detail project with Core Data in Xcode 7 beta 3. When I run it on the simulator (9.0) it looks like this:

[image]

but on my device, iPhone 6 8.4 it looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: I think I narrowed it down to it being a 9.0 vs. 8.4. It looks fine in the 9.0 simulator, but on an 8.4 simulator it has they grey...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by manually setting the background color on the tableview.

self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()